# Using an Esri colour ramp in MapInfo

Tags: arcgis-desktop, mapinfo, color-ramp

I have a MapInfo 11 user who wishes to use ArcGIS 10.3.1 colour ramps. I'd like a seamless method to get from A to B.

So far I've screen grabbed the ramp and saved it as a raster, exported it to points,  calculated the raster's RGB values into the attribute table, and run a frequency on the table.. This gave me a list of all the RGB combinations in the ramp. Apparently MapInfo users can import RGB values.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using "out of the box" MapInfo, then I don't think there is a direct way to import the values from ESRI.

However, from what you have, done already, you can modify the "theme" of a raster in MapInfo.  Below is a Slope Analysis layer that I have brought into MapInfo.  Note, the file is a .flt file which in MapInfo is considered a "GRID". [image]

By default, Mapinfo takes the Minimum and Maximum values and stretches between them as a black and white layer.

[image]

Next, click on the "Modify Theme" button:
[image]

Then click on "Styles..."

[image]

You can change the number of inflections to up to 16.  This will give you several values to work with.

[image]

Then you can edit the colours as well as the values of the inflections.

[image]

Note there are extensions to MapInfo such as [**Encom Discover**](http://www.pitneybowes.com/us/location-intelligence/geographic-information-systems/mapinfo-discover-3d.html) which may have more functionality in this arena.

Also, these screenshots were done in MapInfo 15, but I think the functionality still exists in version 11.